# How to iterate over list of key-value tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, tuples

I have sorted the dictionary using sorted() method and it returns a list of key-value tuples as:-

```
MyDict = {'a': 8, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h' :1}
data = sorted(MyDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(data)
```

Output:-

```
[('a', 8), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('g', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]
```

Now, I want to iterate over it using for loop and print the keys as well as values that are divisible by k (k can me any integer number). This seems a basic question, but I am a beginner and it seems tricky to me. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? The looping? The division?

Comment: The looping part @deceze.

Comment: Do you need to convert the dictionary to list of tuples ?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, variable and function name should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = 4
data = [('a', 8), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 1), ('g', 1), ('h', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 0)]

for item in data:
    if item[1] % k == 0:
        print('Key = %s, Value = %.i' % (item[0], item[1]))
```

Output:

```
Key = a, Value = 8
Key = b, Value = 4
Key = e, Value = 0
Key = f, Value = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
num = 1

for key, value in data:
    if value % num == 0:
        print("Key: {0} Value: {1}".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to convert the dictionary to list of tuples for doing that.
Try this :

```
MyDict = {'a': 8, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h' :1}

k = 2   # it can be any value as you say

for key,val in MyDict.iteritems():
    if val%k ==0:
        print("Key - {0} and value - {1}".format(key,val))
```

If you still need to convert the given dictionary to list of tuples and then use it, here is how you can do it.

```
MyDict = {'a': 8, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 1, 'h' :1}
data = sorted(MyDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

k = 2  # any int value you want.

for item in data:
    if item[1]%k == 0:
        print("Key - {0} and value - {1}".format(item[0],item[1]))
```